# How to use html files externally in nodejs (Not internal html)?

Tags: node.js, email, templates

I want to send multiple mails by using nodejs. Currently I am using the html code inside the Nodejs script of Route. But when html is going large the Nodejs file also going huge and it is not maintainability.

So how can I use html files externally ?

I am using `nodemailer` code externally. Like that I also want to use `html` file externally (`/api/htmls/registerEmail.html`). But the `html` file also using body data also (`req.body.fname`)

**mailSender.js (/api/routes/r_msg/)**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

function sendMail(to, msg, subject)    
{

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

  host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'sample@sample.com',
      pass: 'password'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'sample@sample.com',
  to:to,
  subject: subject,
  html: msg,
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info)
{
  if (error)
  {
    console.log(error);
  } 
})

}

module.exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

**register.js (/api/routes/)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const sendMail = require("../api/routes/r_msg");

router.post("/register/new", (req, res) =>
{
    const newStudent = new Student(
    {
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname,
        contact_no: req.body.lname,
        email : req.body.email
    });

    newStudent.save()
    .then(student =>
    {
        if (student)
        {
            //This line want to change
            var html = `<html> <body> Hello ` + req.body.fname + `Welcome </body> </html>`;

            sendMail.sendMail(req.body.email, html, 'Success');
            res.status(200).send(setting.status("Success")
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ejs` module ? then you build the needed templates in external files and the templates can be render as you need

Comment: No how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can solve it with [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs).

Add this to your **register.js**:

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const renderFile = promisify(ejs.renderFile);

// inside route handler:

renderFile(__dirname + "/api/htmls/registerEmail.html", {fname: req.body.fname})
    .then(html => {
        sendMail.sendMail(req.body.email, html, 'Success');        
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle error
    })
```

Email template **registerEmail.html**

```
<html> <body> Hello <%= fname %> Welcome </body> </html>
```

Comment: I got an error `ReferenceError: promisify is not defined`

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot to add one line. Updated my answer.